# Functional Analysis - How is this function expanded?

Tags: calculus, integration, taylor-expansion

I am struggling to understand an answer for a good few hours now.
I've got
$\int{\ln(1+x^2y')dx}$ with some boundary conditions.
$y$ and $h$ being continuous differentiable functions.

Then for $\delta= S[y+\epsilon h] - S[y]$ I can see the expansion is
$\delta= \epsilon \int (x^2 h')/ (1+x^2 y') - \epsilon ^2 / 2 \int (x^4 h' ^2)/ (1+x^2 y')^2  + O( \epsilon ^2).$

Now I get that you can expand initial $S[y]$ to get $\int{\ln(1+x^2(y+ \epsilon h)')dx}$
and use Taylor series to expand it, but my series looks like $\delta= \epsilon \int (x^2 h')/ 1 - \epsilon ^2 / 2 \int (x^4 h' ^2)/ 2  + O( \epsilon ^2),$ because of expansion of $\ln(1+x) = x - x^2/2 + x^3/3 + ...$

I don't understand where that denominator comes from.

Comment: Notice that $\ln(1+x^2(y'+\epsilon h'))=\ln(1+x^2y')+\ln\left(1+\frac{\epsilon h'}{1+x^2y'}\right)$.